# ¿Cómo cargar un modelo de predicción una vez y no en cada llamada del script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket

Tengo una API muy sencilla que predice la presencia, o no, de comportamientos inseguros al volante. Además de identificar la no regularidad del comportamiento, el API permite caracterizar la infracción cometida.

La API también permite generar un mapa de calor para localizar qué parte de la imagen permitió a los modelos hacer sus predicciones.

Hasta hoy la API carga el modelo `ClassificationModel` cada predicción que lo pidemos sobre el imagen pasada por el script en. Como cargar el modelo solo una vez?

`main.py`

```
from model import ClassificationModel
import argparse
import os


def predict_img(img_path, with_heatmap=False):
    model = ClassificationModel() <--- Aqui descargo el modelo cada vez que llamo a predict_img

    row = model.predict(img_path=img_path, row=None, img=None, load=True, original_image_path=img_path,
                        print_heatmap=with_heatmap)

    results = row.to_json()
    print(results)

    return results


if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--path", "-p", help="path of the image", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--heatmap", "-heat", help="generate heatmap or not", required=True)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if not(os.path.exists(args.path)):
        raise FileNotFoundError("{} does not exist.".format(args.path))

    elif args.path.split(".")[-1] not in ["png", "jpg", "jpeg"]:
        raise TypeError("The file is not a valid image file.")

    if args.heatmap.upper() == "TRUE":
        args.heatmap = True
    else:
        args.heatmap = False

    result = predict_img(img_path=args.path, with_heatmap=args.heatmap)
```

`model.py`

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(40)
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

import settings as st

from predict import Predict


class ClassificationModel(Predict):
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_pos = [
            "safe driving",
            "texting - right",
            "talking to the phone - right",
            "texting - left",
            "talking on the phone - left",
            "operating the radio",
            "drinking",
            "reaching behind",
            "hair and makeup",
            "talking to passenger"
        ]

        self.image_size = 384
        self.generator = ImageDataGenerator(brightness_range=[0.7, 1.5],
                                            rotation_range=35,
                                            fill_mode='nearest',
                                            zoom_range=0.125,
                                            rescale=1. / 255)

        self.model = load_model(st.model_path)
        self.threshold = 0.5
        self.n_step = 5
        self.normal_index = 0
```

`settings.py`

```
model_path = "./model/classification.h5"

th = [0.5,
      0.5,
      0.5,
      0.5,
      0.5,
      0.5,
      0.5,
      0.5,
      0.5,
      0.5]
```

Pensé en hacer un bucle while desde el principio. Gentes me aconsejaron hacer un sistema que espere unos datos de entrada vía http/sockets pero no sé como hacer esto.

Comment: si cargas el modelo en cada llamada a la función, por que no lo pones a fuera de la función? y solo lo utilizas cuando sea necesario

Comment: Porque en este caso el modelo se llamaría de cualquier manera, @Christian . La idea que se me ocurre es hacer algo que se ejecute permanentemente (para que sólo cargue el modelo una vez) y que se encargue de las peticiones que le enviemos utilizando este modelo. Probablemente con un bucle while y haciendo peticiones http/socket